# Can asyncio be used with http.client?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently using threads to make multiple "asynchronous" requests to download files. It has been suggested to me to look into using `asyncio` now that we have upgraded to Python 3+.

We have to use `ssl.SSLContext(protocol = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)` and pass PEM and KEY files.

Can I just work to convert my `http.client` script to be used with `asyncio` or do I need to convert the `http.client` functions to `aiohttp` functions?

**Bonus:**

Either way, could somebody outline how to choose between `async def`  and `@asyncio.coroutine`?

**Supporting Info:**

My program performs fairly well considering that our last one which was a sequential query and now works in parallel with around 15 concurrent requests. However another program I am working on sends upwards for 500 requests in parallel; I could use a `threading.Semaphore()` but I have read that `asyncio` is great for large volume requests.

First time messing around with it, so...

I'm reading the [following](http://aosabook.org/en/500L/a-web-crawler-with-asyncio-coroutines.html) (and like 80% of it seems like socket connection for non-blocking sockets, and the only applicable section is "Coordinating Coroutines").

Comment: Bonus: does your Python version support the `async`/`await` syntax? Then use it. The decorator was just a stopover until that syntax was in place.

Comment: Yes, you want to use asyncio and use aiohttp. The latter should support SSL just fine (you can pass in a `ssl.SSLContext()` to the TCPConnector, which you then pass to the ClientSession).

Comment: And use Python 3.5 or (preferably) 3.6 so you can just use `async` / `await` everywhere, forget about `@asyncio.coroutine`.

Comment: take a look at [`aiohttp`](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: @deceze How would one determine which functions need to be `async`? For example, `main()` simple builds a list of threads which subclasses of a `threading.Thread`. If I got rid of the subclass but turned its functionality into a standalone `def ()`, would I put `async` only with that function?

Comment: Any function that `awaits` another function in its body is by its definition asynchronous and must be annotated with `async`. It's pretty much that simple. If you're calling an `async` function in your function and you want to wait for its result (as opposed to just letting it finish sometime later on its own), you must `await` it.

Comment: @deceze Okay so if the function is `async` and does a `respsonse.read()` and doesn't return anything, the calling function doesn't need to `await`; but if I was waiting for the response from the `async` function called, I would need to `await` the call?

Comment: I believe what you're saying it correct, yes. Note that you'll need to wrap an async functions you're *not* awaiting in something like `asyncio.ensure_future` though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aiohttp`; you'll need to translate your `http.client` code to use [`aiohttp` client API](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html). You can re-use your `ssl.SSLContext()` object; pass it to a [`TCPConnector()` instance](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp-client-reference-connectors), then create a client from that:

```
import aiohttp
import ssl


SSL_CONTEXT = ssl.SSLContext(protocol=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
SSL_CONTEXT.load_cert_chain(certfile='foo', keyfile='bar')


async def fetch_url(url):
    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl_context=SSL_CONTEXT)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(conn=connector) as client:
        async with client.get(url) as response:
            print(resp.status)
            print(await resp.text())
```

Note that you can't share the connector between client sessions; if you want to re-use, reuse the client.

Comment: Connections need to be HTTPS, so can `aiohttp` support that as well as with an occasional need for a proxy? Also, you didn't import `asyncio` but declared `async`; can you do that??

Comment: @madeslurpy: `aiohttp` supports SSL connections just fine, and [supports using a proxy](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html#proxy-support) (configured per request or per client). The `async` syntax is part of the language, you don't have to import `asyncio` to enable it.

Comment: So when/why would I need to import `asyncio`? All the examples I have been reading makes calls to `get_event_loop()` and `run_until_complete()`. Do I not need those to make 500 simultaneous, parallel requests for file downloads?

Comment: @madeslurpy: yes, you do, you'll need to get an event loop going and run your async tasks under that. I didn't include that here, I only included the async function to do a request as a sample. If you need to have a complete async tutorial then this is rapidly getting too broad.